# How to modify haskell function to remove duplicates

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have this haskell function that flattens a two deep list into one list. How can I edit it to make sure that it doesn't allow for duplicates? An example would be

```
flatten[['a'],[],['a','b']] --> ['a','b']
```

My current program would output

```
['a','a','b']

flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten []            = []
flatten ([]:vs)       = flatten vs
flatten ((x:xs):vs)   = x:flatten (xs:vs)
```

Comment: I am just wanting to flatten a list of lists [[a]] into a single list [a] with no duplicates

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve deduplification? If so, what went wrong?

Comment: `nub` is the hard-to-google name you need.

Comment: `nub` is O(n^2) and might not be the name you need depending on what you want.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, I have tried to do some checking such as if xs == x, try and call the function again. But I do not understand how to essentially skip over duplicates.

Comment: Hint: your `flatten` is just `concat`. And to flatten and remove duplicates, use `nub . concat`.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right, it is an implementation of concat, but I am trying to do things without using built in functions as best I can (I should have mentioned that earlier)

Comment: @PushedCrayon OK. Still, you should only implement the duplicate elimination (`nub`) on the flat list and then compose it with the `concat` implementation, instead of trying to do everything at once.

Answer (score 4):

Skipping over duplicates in an unsorted list requires keeping a set of already-seen elements, and checking every incoming element.

Something like:

```
dedupliction_step :: [a] -> SetOf a -> [a] -> [a]

deduplication_step [] _ output = output
dedupliction_step (x:rest) already_seen output = 
  if x `belongsTo` already_seen then deduplication_step rest already_seen output
  else deduplication_step rest updated_seen x:output where
    updated_seen = putElementInto already_seen x
```

This gives you the idea. How do you implement `SetOf` and its related manipulations, depends on the problem at hand.

For short sets, you can use `SetOf` = `List`; then `belongsTo` = `elem`. It has a linear lookup time, though, so for long sets it becomes expensive.

For long sets, you can use e.g. a `Data.Tree` or `Data.Set` with logarithmic lookup and update time.

For short sets of numbers, `Data.Bits` could be considered; it's O(1) lookup and update, but limited to 32 or 64 values.

Comment: Would there be any way to possibly look ahead at the next item in a list and compare it to the current item? If they are similar you could skip over it.. I don't know if that is a possibility in Haskell

Comment: @PushedCrayon Yes: Try the pattern guard `f (x1:x2:xs) | x1 == x2 = f (x2:xs)`.  The type of the list elements must be an instance of `Eq` for `==` to be defined.